# Weird behaviour seen in Debug Logs, CODE_UNIT_FINISHED is not coming in debug logs

Tags: apex, debugging

I was reviewing one of my debug logs and I found that my debug logs are coming in the following way for one of my person account records. You can notice that CODE_UNIT_FINISHED is missing from the debug logs. Ideally, before trigger code unit must finish before running validation or before running after update trigger by using "CODE_UNIT_FINISHED" in the debug logs. Do you have any idea why "CODE_UNIT_FINISHED" is missing from the debug logs ?

> CODE_UNIT_STARTED | AccountTrigger on PersonAccount trigger event BeforeUpdate for [0019E00000C8dR9]
>
> CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:PersonAccount:0019E00000C8dR9
>
> CODE_UNIT_STARTED | AccountTrigger on PersonAccount trigger event
>   AfterUpdate for [0019E00000C8dR9]
>
> CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Account

Although, after a workflow field update gets fired, then triggers run again. This time I am able to see the  CODE_UNIT_FINISHED log as expected.

> CODE_UNIT_STARTED | AccountTrigger on PersonAccount trigger event BeforeUpdate for [0019E00000C8dR9] .
>
> CODE_UNIT_FINISHED | AccountTrigger on PersonAccount trigger event BeforeUpdate for [0019E00000C8dR9]
>
> CODE_UNIT_STARTED | AccountTrigger on PersonAccount trigger event AfterUpdate for [0019E00000C8dR9] .
>
> CODE_UNIT_FINISHED | AccountTrigger on PersonAccount trigger event AfterUpdate for [0019E00000C8dR9]

Does anyone have any idea, why it may happen ? Thanks

Comment: Is that log got truncated?

Comment: I truncated the logs while asking question here. The question is why I am not getting CODE_UNIT_FINISHED in the log after a code unit for e.g. before trigger finishes.